# Monterey VM reboot loop and kernel panic in VirtualBox 6.1.32 (on Apple host hardware)

Tags: kernel-panic, virtualization, virtualbox, intel

#### Environment

- Apple MBA 2020 MacBook Air9,1 / Intel / x86_64 machine
- Host OS: macOS Big Sur 11.6.2
- Host OS Build: 20G314
- SW: VirtualBox 6.1.32 r149290 (also tried on VirtualBox 6.1.30 r148432)
- Guest OS: macOS Monterey 12.1 (21C52)

#### Purpose

- Upgrade VM from Big Sur 11.6.2 (fully functional with VB 6.1.32) to Monterey 12.1.

  OR
- Installation from scratch a Monterey VM. Both have same final result: instability.

After the first boot with Monterey, the VM suddenly HANGS AND REBOOTED BY ITSELF, reporting "This system was automatically rebooted after panic".
It seems it enters in a "reboot loop" because after some time, even doing nothing, a reboot still happen again and again, like in an infinite loop.

#### How to reproduce

1. Open VB 6.1.32

2a. Start a VM upgraded to Monterey

OR
2b. Start a VM installed from scratch with Monterey

OR
2.c Start a VM with "Install macOS Monterey ISO" as only Storage added to VM (NO other Hardisk present)

3. Just wait some time...

==> You'll see in 0-15 min Guest OS HANGS AND SUDDENLY REBOOTS by itself.

==> Then the console message is: "This system was automatically rebooted after panic"

#### Logs and info

I unfortunately continue to note the instability of Monterey as Guest with VB 6.1.32, even on Apple Hardware!

All config data, and a video are at disposal to have an idea, as well as VB Logs (see attachments).

- VirtualBox 6.1.32 Logs: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pcvHhReFDUKKYQJoSo0-c7S84K8HD2Rw/view?usp=sharing
- Monterey (VB 6.1.32) reboot loop video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F5xHo5DTnD2z9Sc5Lw7P2w4EUscepDR2/view?usp=sharing

#### Questions

I asked to VirtualBox forum here [topic 104998](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=104998) with hope of receiving helpful feedback, which has not been the case as yet.

I'm primarily interested in sharing to the community and finding other user experiences.

Does the same or similar behaviour happens to someone else?

Has anyone perhaps applied a workaround or found a fix?

Has anyone ever gotten a really stable and usable Monterey guest installation (on Mac HW) with VirtualBox?

---

## Added later...

I just came back a few days later, just for a minor update on this topic.

I was wandering if something changed with Monterey (Host), perhaps hardware resources are managed differently in Monterey, or that more generally something has changed.

So I just repeated the tasks with the same VM, so VirtualBox 6.1.32 with Monterey (Guest) on Monterey (Host on Apple hardware)

#### Environment (revised)

- Apple MBA 2020 MakBookAir9,1 / Intel / x86_64 machine
- **Host OS: macOS Monterey 12.1**
- **Host OS Build: 21C52**
- SW: VirtualBox 6.1.32 r149290
- Guest OS: macOS Monterey 12.1 (21C52)

I unfortunately note that the result is still the same: VM do a reboot loop and kernel panic.

Comment: You might consider using VMware Fusion Player. The non-commercial license is free. I have Monterey installed on a 2013 iMac host.

Comment: Thx @DavidAnderson for your proof. I certainly will consider that, as well as moving all other VM I have (Linux, Win). VB has always been great to my needs. In the VB 6.1.30 release notes they say: "VBoxHeadless: Fixed crash when running on macOS Monterey (bug #20636)" and "macOS host: fix multiple bugs specific to macOS Monterey in installer and startup of kernel extensions"
And I am sorry to see that this is not the case to me as yet, despite what they claim.

Comment: @villoez have you tried `RealTSCOffset` solultion? Your logs don't have it. If yes, please post new logs with this setting.

Answer (score 32):

After some research, the problem seems to be about TSC (Time Stamp Counter) emulation.

The following worked for me:

1. Close ALL VirtualBox windows (otherwise the next setting will be overwritten)
2. Run commandline command, where `YOUR_VM_NAME` is the name of your VM:
   `VBoxManage setextradata "YOUR_VM_NAME" "VBoxInternal/TM/TSCMode" "RealTSCOffset"`
3. If you still see kernel panics, double-check that your `.vbox` file contains the applied settings and also check VM's logs for errors related to `RealTSCOffset`.

Comment: Absolute legend @Codeguard!

Comment: This worked for me on a Hackintosh with Virtualbox 6.1. It kept crashing with panic at continue after choosing to install.

Comment: Hi, 
Adding the parameter RealTSCOffset to my VM seems to resolve the issue.
Thanks very much, your answer save my day. cheers ;)))))

Comment: Top answer @Codeguard worked like a charm!!!

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks @Codeguard for this fix.
After that you can even up the number of CPUs - I have four working fine with Monterey 12.6 on VirtualBox v 6.1.40 on Linux (Xeon)

Comment: saved my day !!!

Comment: This is still required when installing macOS Ventura too. IMHO should be marked as official answer to this thread. Thanks!

Comment: What about VMware?

Comment: This helped somewhat but at the end of the installer the panic still appears.

Answer (score 15):

I found that changing number of virtual CPUs to 1 helps. But then it's slower, of course.

Comment: Yup, that did the trick for me too.

Comment: Setting cpu to 1 worked.

Answer (score 0):

I still need to try @Codeguard answer, but for me it appears that changing my GraphicsController from VBoxSVGA to VBoxVGA fixed the issue.